# How do I create a list that contain all my conditions without ending with a long if elif stament in Python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, conditional-statements, set

I am new to coding with Python, (only a few days), and I have encountered many issues already, However, one seems to be persistent. Every time I create a condition I end up with a long list of if-else statements. I searched the website but could not figure out how to find a solution to my specific issue.

I am building a simple unit converter. The code is below:

```
def get_unit1():
      while True:
          unit1 = input("Which unit would you like to convert from?: ")
          if unit1 == 'km':                                              
              return unit1
          elif unit1 == 'hm':
              return unit1
          elif unit1 == 'da':
              return unit1
          elif unit1 == 'm':
              return unit1
          elif unit1 == 'dm':
              return unit1
          elif unit1 == 'cm':
              return unit1
          elif unit1 == 'mm':
              return unit1
          elif unit1 == 'ml':
              return unit1
          elif unit1 == 'yd':
              return unit1
          elif unit1 == 'ft':
              return unit1
          elif unit1 == 'in':
              return unit1    
          else:
              print("Wrong input, try again.")

  def get_unit2():
      while True:
          unit2 = input("Which unit would you like to convert to?: ")
          if unit2 == 'km':                                              
              return unit2
          elif unit2 == 'hm':
              return unit2
          elif unit2 == 'da':
              return unit2
          elif unit2 == 'm':
              return unit2
          elif unit2 == 'dm':
              return unit2
          elif unit2 == 'cm':
              return unit2
          elif unit2 == 'mm':
              return unit2
          elif unit2 == 'ml':
              return unit2
          elif unit2 == 'yd':
              return unit2
          elif unit2 == 'ft':
              return unit2
          elif unit2 == 'in':
              return unit2    
          else:
              print("Wrong input, try again.")
```

The condition is working perfectly fine, it's just that it is long.
When I shrink the condition using OR operator for example:

```
if unit1 == 'km'or'hm'or'da'or'm'or'dm'or'cm'or'mm'or'ml'or'yd'or'ft'or'in':
                return unit1
```

It does work too but when I put the wrong input it accepts it and later the program crashes.

I tried using a list but ended up creating a long code of "if x in list" statements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a list of all your true values and just ask something like **if unit1 in myvalues**

Comment: For simple conversions, you might consider a dictionary to make a _mapping_ to convert different types into a common type (for example kilometers, feet, inches, to meters) and then the reverse to get a final result! If it's not for a dedicated assignment, but some project / personal interest, check out [Pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) ([GH](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint))'s unit conversion features!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in` to test if something is in a list.

```
UNITS = ['km', 'hm', 'da', 'm', 'dm', 'cm', 'mm', 'ml', 'yd', 'ft', 'in']

def get_unit(prompt: str) -> str:
    while True:
        unit = input(prompt)
        if unit in UNITS:
            return unit
        print("Wrong input, try again.")

def get_unit1() -> str:
    return get_unit("Which unit would you like to convert from?: ")

def get_unit2() -> str:
    return get_unit("Which unit would you like to convert to?: ")
```

A common way to handle the situation where you want input to be one of a specific set of values is to create an `Enum` that enumerates all the values.  You can construct an `Enum` by giving it one of the values, and it'll automatically raise `ValueError` if the value is invalid, only constructing an instance of that Enum if the value is one of the ones you listed.  In this example that might look like this:

```
from enum import Enum

class Unit(Enum):
    KILOMETER = 'km'
    HECTOMETER = 'hm'
    DALTON = 'da'
    METER = 'm'
    DECIMETER = 'dm'
    CENTIMETER = 'cm'
    MILLIMETER = 'mm'
    MILE = 'ml'
    YARD = 'yd'
    FOOT = 'ft'
    INCH = 'in'

def get_unit(prompt: str) -> Unit:
    while True:
        try:
            return Unit(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong input, try again.")

def get_unit1() -> Unit:
    return get_unit("Which unit would you like to convert from?: ")

def get_unit2() -> Unit:
    return get_unit("Which unit would you like to convert to?: ")
```

Having the strings as members of an enum makes it harder to accidentally type them wrong in a different part of the code and create a hard-to-debug problem.  This is important because you'll probably need to reference these values in other places, e.g. in creating a conversion table:

```
METERS_PER_UNIT = {
    Unit.KILOMETER: 1000,
    Unit.HECTOMETER: 100,
    Unit.METER: 1,
    # ... etc
}
```

so that you can do:

```
unit1 = get_unit1()
unit2 = get_unit2()
unit2_per_unit1 = METERS_PER_UNIT[unit1] / METERS_PER_UNIT[unit2]
print(f"1 {unit1.name} is the same as {unit2_per_unit1} {unit2.name}")
```